# Pasar información de un String a un Array

Tags: array, string, swift4

Me gustaría saber si se puede coger un **String** y *meter los valores que quieras en el primer valor de un **array***. Por ejemplo:

```
var Array: Array<String> = []

let cadena = " Hola me llamo Willie "

for x in cadena {
    if x == " " || x == ","  {
        numero2Array.append(" ")
    }else {
        let y = String(x)
        numero2Array.append(y)
    }
}

print(numero2Array)
```

Lo que no se ni encuentro es como hacer para meter por ejemplo la primera parte de la cadena *"Hola"* en la **primera** posición del array. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haría asi:

```
let cadena = " Hola me llamo Willie "
var cadenaArray= split(cadena){$0 == " "}
```

Comment: Da un error: Use of unresolved identifier 'split'

Comment: he intentado hacerlo como propiedad de la cadena : cadena.split(separador: " ") pero resulta que no puedo introducirlo en el array por que es un substring.

Comment: Finalmente lo pude hacer con split() aplicándolo varias veces en una función. Gracias